# Installing/compiling OpenFOAM on a server without admin privileges

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openfoam

I'm trying to install/compile OpenFOAM on a remote server. As I don't have the admin privileges I have to compile it from scratch. Following [the instructions here](https://www.openfoam.com/code/build-guide.php), when I try to run

```
source ~/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/etc/bashrc
```

I get the error:

> No completion added for /home/foobar/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin

I checked the `~/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/etc/bashrc` definitely exists and it is intact. I also checked the `/home/foobar/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/` folder and there are no such thing as `platforms` folder! I searched and the only place I could see a similar error message is [here](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-bugs/197310-possible-missing-tab-completion-ofv1712.html#post676598) where the issue is old Bash. I tried `bash --version` returning `version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` which is more than `4.2` as seems to be required.

**My system information:**

When I run the `uname -a` command on the server this is what I get

> Linux foobar 4.4.0-101-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 18:29:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Looking into the possible required dependencies mentioned in [this page](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/system-requirements.php), I checked the installed packages using the command `apt list --installed | grep -i packageName`, The packages installed are:

> build-essential, flex, bison, cmake, zlib1g-dev, libboost-system-dev, libboost-thread-dev, libopenmpi-dev, openmpi-bin, gnuplot, libreadline-dev, libqt4-dev, libqt4-opengl-dev, freeglut3-dev,

And the ones not installed are:

> libncurses-dev, libxt-dev, libqtwebkit-dev, libcgal-dev

which according to the installation page are not essential I suppose.

and checking the versions of the libraries installed:

- `mpirun --version` -->  `(Open MPI) 1.10.2`
- `gcc --version` --> `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609`
- `cmake --version` --> `3.5.1`

I would appreciate if could let me know

1. What is the problem and how I can solve it?
2. if not solvable, what are the alternative methods for me to have the OpenFOAM installed/compiled on the said server.

Comment: As always, if you really think there is something wrong with a post it would be a great help to provide more info alongside a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really embracing as it was just a wrong error! I was informed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openfoam/s7yELMQAK1E) that I could have ignored the error and go forward with compiling. Of course I couldn't compile the ParaVIEW/paraFoam as dependencies lack, but it is just a headless server without any GUI. So if you got this error just ignore it and go forwards with the compiling with:

```
./Allwmake
```

I have reported the issue [here](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/OpenFOAM-plus/issues/719) so they can fix it.

P.S. I reported this issue almost 9 month ago and now there is a new confusing message instead of the old one!

> No completion added for /home/foobar/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin
>   ... incorrect platform, or not yet compiled?